# how to capture Build Info using Gradle and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to get access to build info values such as `version` in my Java main application using Spring Boot and Gradle.

I can't find any documentation / examples of how to configure the

- `build.gradle`
- `application.yml` (if required)
- `Java main class`

could someone please help with a small code example for the above files.

In my `build.gradle` file I will have the `version` entry, so how to get this into Java main class using Spring Boot and Gradle.

### build.gradle

```
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I've tried adding

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

springBoot {    
    buildInfo() 
}
```

but the `buildInfo()` isn't recognised as a keyword in Intellij

In my Java main class I have the following:

```
public class MyExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Environment env = (Environment) context.getBean("environment");
        displayInfo(env);
    }

    private static void displayInfo(Environment env) {
       log.info("build version is <" + env.getProperty("version")     
    }
```

But when I run this - the output from `env.getProperty("version")` is showing as `null`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring Boot auto-configures a `BuildProperties` bean with the information generated by `buildInfo()`.

So to get the information use `context.getBean(BuildProperties.class).getVersion();`.

Comment: thank you Vampire. I've change my code as you've suggested but now getting an exception,

Description:

A component required a bean of type,
'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'buildProperties' in 'ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnResource did not find resource '${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}'

I am not running a web-application this is a stand-alone Springboot app.

Comment: I am marking your reply as an Answer because it helped me along quite a bit. If you agree with my Answer and sample code then can you please also mark it as an Answer as I cant mark my own

Comment: One possibility for not finding the build-info.properties is using bootRun to run the project. I don't know the recommended way to have both bootRun and buildinfo working.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to get it working now - using the help pointer that Vampire gave below and some other sources. The key was adding the actuator class to the project dependency.
Note: Intellj doesn't seem to recognise buildInfo() in the springBoot tag - but it does run ok - so don't be put off.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
        gradleVersion = '3.3'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "http://cft-nexus.ldn.xxxxxxxxx.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        additionalProperties = ['foo': 'bar']
    }
}

compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
```

**MyExampleApplication**

```
@Slf4j
@EnableIntegration
@EnableLoaderApplication
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MyExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final String SYSTEM_NAME_INFO = "My Example Application";
    private static final String VERSION="0.0.1";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BuildProperties buildProperties = context.getBean(BuildProperties.class);
        displayInfo(buildProperties);
    }

    private static void displayInfo(BuildProperties buildProperties) {
        log.info("build version is <" + buildProperties.getVersion() + ">");
    log.info("value for custom key 'foo' is <" + buildProperties.get("foo") + ">");
    }

}
```

**Screenshot of Console output when running the Application in Intellj**
[image: Console Output when running the application is shown below]

*pasting the output as well incase the image doesn't display*

```
> 2017-11-14 14:35:47.330  INFO 22448 --- [           main]
> o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase
> 2147483647 2017-11-14 14:35:47.448  INFO 22448 --- [           main]
> s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s):
> 8780 (http) 2017-11-14 14:35:47.451  INFO 22448 --- [           main]
> c.u.o.metrics.MyExampleApplication         : build version is
> <0.0.1-SNAPSHOT> 2017-11-14 14:35:47.451  INFO 22448 --- [          
> main] c.u.o.myexample.MyExampleApplication         : value for custom key
> 'foo' is <bar>
```

**UPDATE**

After reviewing this with my colleague we decided to move the some of the build properties, e.g. `version` (above) out of the `build.gradle` file and into `gradle.properties` file. This gives us a cleaner separation for build details and properties. When you run Gradle build it automatically pulls these values in and they are available in the BuildProperties bean in the Java main class as shown in the example above.

**gradle.properties**

```
group=com.xxx.examplesource
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT 
gradleVersion=3.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you know where the springBoot buildInfo additionalProperties approach is documented? Strangely, the similar but different approach shown here doesn't work: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/

Comment: Thanks dude. I was unaware of this weird thing in IDE intellij IDEA. Its working when i running in docker container :)

Answer (score 3):

add following to your Gradle script.It inserts the version into the jar manifest correctly, as shown here:

```
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}
```

Your code will be able to pick up the version from that jar manifest file:

```
public class BuildVersion {
    public static String getBuildVersion(){
        return BuildVersion.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    }
}
```

Refer the link below for more details: https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff/wiki/Manifest-attributes-in-build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to get version number in Spring boot

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class WebController {

private final BuildProperties buildProperties;

public WebController(BuildProperties properties) {
    buildProperties = properties;
}

@GetMapping("/test")
public String index() {

    System.out.println(buildProperties.getVersion());
    System.out.println(buildProperties.getArtifact());
    System.out.println(buildProperties.getGroup());
    System.out.println(buildProperties.getName());
    System.out.println(buildProperties.getTime());

    return "index";
}
}
```

And dont forget generate application-build.properties

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

Comment: Probably easier just to leverage the built-in Spring Boot 'info' Actuator (`/actuator/info`)  after calling `buildInfo` in the gradle build, rather than rolling your own controller method

Comment: @runderworld   How can this be done for springboot war file deployed in a standalone tomcat?