# How can I get application version and some other info from gradle using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Can you explain me how can i get application version and some otger info from my Spring Boot application ?

I'm using gradle project builder.

I think it will be cool, if I would can get application version from build.gradle file (for example)

```
version = '0.0.2-SNAPSHOT'
```

and then I need to increment this number.
I need to do this every time I make a new application build.
Then I have to get this information in Java code and transfer it to the frontend (AngularJS) so that the QA can know the current version of the application.

Can you explain me how can I do this ?
I will be very grateful if you tell me how to do it.

Thanks a lot!

---

**UPDATED:**

I thought a little and realized that it might be easier to write a script on Groovy and directly in the "build.gradle" file to take the current version of the application in some way, then increase it by 1 (+1) then somehow remember this version (overwrite it in the "build.gradle" file) and get it in the JAVA code.
Maybe it’s too complicated what I said, but that’s all I can say.

Maybe someone has any ideas on this?
I will be grateful for the help and useful links as it can be done.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: Which spring-boot version 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: @netfalo 1.5.12 version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to capture Build Info using Gradle and Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283048/how-to-capture-build-info-using-gradle-and-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I did it.

```
public String getManifestInfo() {
        return getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    }
```

after application build I got application version from MANIFEST.MF file from my jar file.

Some code from my build-gradle file

```
tasks.register("incrementVersion") {
    doFirst {
        def ver = version
        println ver
        String lastNumber = ver.substring(ver.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
        int increment = lastNumber.toInteger() + 1
        println increment

        String firstNumber = ver.substring(0, ver.lastIndexOf("."))
        println firstNumber
        String result = buildFile.getText().replaceFirst("version='$version'","version='" + firstNumber + "." + increment + "'")
        buildFile.setText(result)
    }
}

jar.dependsOn incrementVersion
bootJar.dependsOn incrementVersion

bootJar {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                    'Main-Class': 'com.example.appinfo.AppinfoApplication',
                    'Implementation-Title': 'Application Info project',
                    'Implementation-Version': "${version}"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!