# Custom properties in Spring Boot project using Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

In my Spring Boot project (1.5.6.RELEASE) that I build using gradle, I want to include some custom properties. The approach laid out in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/) does not seem to work (on build, I get: `Could not set unknown property 'additional' for task ':properties' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.PropertyReportTask.`):

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            additional = [
                'a': 'alpha',
                'b': 'bravo'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Luckily this approach, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288548/3368818), does work for me (no compile error and I'm then able to access the property from my code):

```
springBoot{
    buildInfo {
        additionalProperties = [
            'testpropertykey': 'testpropertyvalue'
        ]
    }
}
```

But, since the former is the "officially" documented approach, I would prefer to take that approach. How would I get the former approach to work? I assume I'm missing something - unless the documentation is wrong or maybe this changed from Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE.

Comment: My guess is the syntax changed between the Spring Boot version I'm using (1.5.6.RELEASE) and the current version that the docs refer to. Can't find documentation of the old approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs you linked are for the **current** version of the plugin which aligns with the current GA version of Spring Boot: 2.1.7

Version 1.5.x of the plugin does have a `additionalProperties` field: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/buildinfo/BuildInfo.java#L66

The 2.1.x version does not and you use `properties` instead: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/buildinfo/BuildInfo.java#L45

Suggest you migrate/upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1.x or 2.2.x when that is released soon since 1.5.x has already reached EOL: https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/30/spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know if any docs are accessible anywhere for older Spring Boot versions? Can't seem to find any.

Comment: So for 2.1+ it is `buildInfo.properties.additionalProperties`